# qt c++ QPaint with QVector

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I have a ***QVector*** in  my **drawingwidget.h**

```
QVector<QPoint> m_vertices;
```

I want to draw multiple vertices.
I am currently doing simple drawing tool, but i can only draw one circle.

```
void DrawingWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(event->rect(), Qt::blue);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
    //painter.drawEllipse(m_x - 10, m_y - 10, 20, 20);
}
void DrawingWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    if(m_state == ADD_VERTEX_SELECTED) {
        if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            m_x = event->x();
            m_y = event->y();
            update();
        }
    }
}
```

How can i draw an array ?

```
painter.drawEllipse(m_vertices[i], 10, 20, 20); ???
```

Comment: you need a loop

Answer (score 1):

That helps.

```
for(int i = 0; i < m_vertices.size(); i++ {
     painter.drawEllipse(m_vertices[i], 20, 20);
   }
```